# Where can I find sample code on mouse movements and polygon spins in OpenGL?

Tags: java, opengl

Where can I find sample code on mouse movements and polygon spins in OpenGL?
I am using Java, so sample code in Java is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably find this useful:

http://pepijn.fab4.be/software/nehe-java-ports/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use the JOGL java libraries very useful sample code can be found [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/kmconroy/JOGLTutorial/).

JOGL is pretty straight foreword and easy to grasp. Just be aware, the object oriented nature might make future/more advanced work with OpenGL in C/C++ a bit harder to grasp.

**MainWindow.java** in the .zip below is an example of exactly what your looking for. The code comes from the above link.
[code.zip](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~meesh/kmconroy/JOGLTutorial/code.zip)